# Unable to autoload constant Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have a form that I am using for new and edit, and the functionality for index and clicking for a new form and edit works, but when I go to create or update the form returns a load error to another controller.

The controller is PathCreationsController in system and it wants to use the creations controller in another place and it wants to use it to define it..which is weird because I don't have anything set to do that.

I tried adding a url to the form and setting the method to put but when I do that to try and force the controller to work correctly it sets all the params to null in the database so I assumed thats not a valid way to fix this.

Here is the controller:

```
class System::PathCreationsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @paths = Path::Account.all
  end

  def new
    @paths = Path::Account.new
  end

  def edit
    @paths = Path::Account.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @paths = Path::Account.new

    if @paths.save
      redirect_to system_path_creations_path(@paths)
    end
  end


  def update
    @path = Path::Account.find_by(slug: params[:id])
    if @path.update
      redirect_to system_path_creations_path(@path)
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the form:

```
    = form_for @paths do |f|
      %br
      .form-group
        = f.label :name, class: 'control-label'
        = f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control'
      .form-group
        = f.label :slug, class: 'control-label'
        = f.text_field :slug, maxlength: 28, class: 'form-control'
      .form-group
        %p.text-muted Click to upload new icon.
        .fileinput.fileinput-new{"data-provides" => "fileinput"}
          %div
            .fileinput-thumbnail.thumbnail{style: 'max-width: 100%;'}
              .fileinput-preview{data: {trigger: "fileinput"}, style: 'max-width: 100%;'}
                = image_tag @firms.try(:logo).try(:present?) ? @life_event.try(:logo).try(:url) : asset_path('/path.svg')
          %div
            %span.btn.btn-default.btn-file.btn-sm{style: 'display: none;'}
              = f.file_field :logo, class: 'file'
              = f.hidden_field :logo_cache
      .form-group
        = f.label :user_id
        = f.select :user_id,  User.all.collect {|u| [#{u.email}", u.id] }

        = f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the create action you never set update the parameters on the model

```
def create
  @paths = Path::Account.new(path_params)
  if @paths.save
    redirect_to system_path_creations_path(@paths)
  end
end
```

you will also need to add

```
def path_params
  params.require(:path_account).permit(:name, :slug, :other, :params, :to, :permit)
end
```

Comment: A couple note on conventions
  Rails looks for the controller (model name pluralized)Controller for a given model name, unless explicitly told otherwise, so for the model Path the controller would be PathsController and the routes would follow /paths/

Secondly: its good practice to use pluralized parameters for arrays and collections and single tense parameters for single objects (i.e. paths for Path::Account.all, but path for Path::Account.new
 This helps down the road recognizing whats in a variable at a glance.

Comment: while this the correct way of doing it, I am now getting where the params are empty

Comment: could you add a copy of the log file showing what parameters are being passed in the request?

Comment: 15:09:51 web.1    |   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "path_account"=>{"name"=>"Test", "slug"=>"test", "logo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f87f3164db0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/lk/0y4764s91077jk_38qg3b8vw0000gn/T/RackMultipart20170601-36917-1bhpiei.jpg>, @original_filename="cassarole.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"path_account[logo]\"; filename=\"cassarole.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "logo_cache"=>"", "user_id"=>"15"}, "commit"=>"Create Account"}

Comment: 15:09:51 web.1    |    (2.8ms)  BEGIN
15:09:51 web.1    |   SQL (7.2ms)  INSERT INTO "path_accounts" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2017-06-01 19:09:51.218409"], ["updated_at", "2017-06-01 19:09:51.218409"]]

Comment: I have added what is being returned and whats being added to the db

Comment: that makes sense, I updated the answer, the params.require() has to match the params coming in

Comment: Did you update the `.permit(:name, :slug, :other, :params, :to, :permit)` to include all the parameters you need to accept?

Comment: yea it permits(:name, :slug, :logo, :used_id) and still doesnt work